# How to separate columns values to create a new different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

It kinda looks like a tuple. But what I want to do is to take all the values after the comma and put them into a new column called **otros_casos**. Therefore, my new df should look like this:

[image]

I don't need those values which have a **3** on it or have a **nan**. Here is the code I am using:

```
dic_cont = data.groupby(['resultado']).otro_caso.value_counts()
data_cont = pd.DataFrame([[key, dic_cont[key]] for key in dic_cont.keys()], columns = ['resultado', 'amount'])
data_cont
```

And here is how *dic_cont* looks like:

[image]

I would really appreciate your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `.str` will unpack tuple

```
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame({"resultado":[(1,pd.np.NaN),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(
    ...: 2,pd.np.NaN),(3,1),(3,2),(3,pd.np.NaN)],"amount":[735709,688554,601864,
    ...: 1055853,693378,596613,196078,182715,122275]})

In [33]:  df['resultado'],df['otros_casos']=df['resultado'].str

In [34]: df = df.dropna()

In [35]: df[df['resultado'] !=3]
Out[35]:
   resultado   amount  otros_casos
1          1   688554          1.0
2          1   601864          2.0
3          2  1055853          1.0
4          2   693378          2.0
```

Comment: I got `FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.`, what is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael, it is `0.25.3`, did not try on the latest version

Comment: @brenda - yes, problem is solution working until upgrade pandas, then rather not use it.